# My network stop responding when trying to transfer files to server share

Tags: windows-7, networking, file-sharing

When I'm trying to transfer files from my server share to my windows 7 and My network doesn't respond.

Every-time I use windows backup to transfer files to the server share or just trying to copy a large file to the server share, it transfers about 800MB-1GB and than suddenly the server share becomes unavailable and the network disconnects.

Every-time that happens I have to go to network and sharing center and disable/enable my network.

Anyone is experiencing this problem and can help me?

**EDIT:** My network card is: Atheros L1 Gigabit Ethernet 10/100/1000Base-T Controller (13/10/2009 v2.4.7.29)

Comment: What's your network driver name/version/date?

Comment: It looks like the problem is with the driver: http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/5787-problems-atheros-l1-ethernet-adapter-win7-x64-3.html - no solution found yet.

Comment: Same same, driver problem: http://forums.pcper.com/showthread.php?t=467443 - no solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> To resolve, I went into the driver
>   properties, clicked Advanced / Task
>   Offload, and I turned this feature
>   off.

[Quoted source](http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/5787-problems-atheros-l1-ethernet-adapter-win7-x64-2.html)

Try it.

Comment: Holy crap holy crap this actually seems to have worked ... thank you!

Comment: Sorry which driver properies? Do you mean Network Adapters? I have D-Link DWA-582 Wireless AC1200 Dual Band PCI Express Adapter, but its Advanced Options have no Task Offload. @Eran Betzalel what about your case?

Comment: @Freelensia, yes, Network Adapters, but I'm not sure that all network drivers have that feature.

Answer (score 1):

I've got this issue also - exact same NIC. No issue with Win 7 32bit as it was working for me then, upgraded to x64 and any time I go to copy files across to another machine it just freezes the machine and im reaching for the reset button. I've also tried the Task Offload - no luck there either.

**Latest drivers fix the issue:**

http://www.station-drivers.com/page/atheros.htm