# Network Copy to Windows 7 File Share Fails and Kills Network Connection

Tags: windows-7, networking

I have a Windows 7 64-bit Home Premium machine that I use as a file server.  This machine is wired to my DLink DIR-655 wireless router.  I share a disk with guest access on that machine.  The network card on this machine is an Atheros L1 Gigabit Ethernet.

On any other machine in the house (Windows XP, Mac OSX), when I copy images over the wireless network to this share the copy will make it part way through, then fail with a message stating the server/share has been disconnected.

Once this failure happens, the Windows 7 file server no longer is connected to the network, and I have to reboot it in order to reconnect to the network.

This file server was upgraded from Windows Vista, where this was not a problem.

I've done a bunch of Google searches, but haven't found any results yet that are the same as this problem.  Any help here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the related items that showed up after I asked this question actually solved this problem for me:

[My network stop responding when trying to transfer files to server share](https://superuser.com/questions/96526/my-network-stop-responding-when-trying-to-transfer-files-to-server-share)